# Wrong vertificate signature algorithm in X509Certificate for SHA256withDSA using Java

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, x509certificate

I am having certificate with key type DSA, bit length 1024, Signature algorithm SHA256:

I am converting it to X509Certificate in java. When I am trying to get signature algorithm from X509Certificate I am getting something like **2.16.840.1.101.3.4.3.2.**

```
CertificateFactory factory=CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate cert=(X509Certificate) factory.generateCertificate(inputStream);
    System.out.println(cert.getSigAlgName());
```

Above method working for all other type (getting name correctly as **SHA256withRSA**). Not working for SHA256withDSA (getting 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.3.2 Expecting **SHA256withDSA**). How can I get correct signature algorithm from certificate? Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: I think you should post more code and less certificates ;-) Just make sure you don't post sensitive information.

Comment: When you say "above method working for all other type", what do you actually get which you believe to be working? Also, you said not working for SHA256withDSA, means getting the signature ID "2.16.840.1.101.3.4.3.2" is not an expected result for you? Could you also tell us the output you get using method cert.getSigAlgName() and see if this output was your expected information you needed?

Comment: @ChaitanyaP  Pls see at Edited question

Comment: @Peanut Thanks I will consider ur point . Certificate is a public information which can be accessed by all.

Comment: Are you running on Java 8, or with customized provider(s)? Only in 8 (or later) does the default provider implement FIPS 186-3 (group sizes 2k and 3k, subgroups 224 and 256, and corresponding SHA-2 hashes).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Running on Java 7

Answer (score 0):

According [X.509 specification Section 4.1.2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280.html#section-4.1.2.3)

> This field contains the algorithm identifier for the algorithm used  by the CA to sign the certificate.
>
> This field MUST contain the same algorithm identifier as the    signatureAlgorithm field in the sequence Certificate (Section 4.1.1.2).  The contents of the optional parameters field will vary  according to the algorithm identified.  [RFC3279], [RFC4055], and  [RFC4491] list supported signature algorithms, but other signature algorithms MAY also be supported.

It's means [X509Certificate#getSigAlgName](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html#getSigAlgName()) returned algorithm used  by the CA to sign the certificate, **not algorithm used by end user (from current certificate) to sign data/document**.

If you need take end-user algorithm, you must using another way.

Eventually you can use one certificate for differents compatible signature algorithms. Example: `RSA` certificate for `SHA1withRSA` and `SHA256withRSA`

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code I tried in Eclipse:

```
     InputStream inStream = null;
     try {
         inStream = new FileInputStream("<cert-file-name-with-path>");
         CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
         X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(inStream);
         System.out.println("##"+cert.getSigAlgName()+"##"+cert.getSigAlgOID()+"##"+cert.getType());
     } finally {
         if (inStream != null) {
             inStream.close();
         }
     }
```

Output:

### SHA256withDSA##2.16.840.1.101.3.4.3.2##X.509

Comment: ##2.16.840.1.101.3.4.3.2##2.16.840.1.101.3.4.3.2##X.509    its my output . What java version you are using

Comment: Java SE 1.8 and I used the Certificate you gave. It works fine.

Comment: here Java SE 1.7 that might be reason too